# What is the best way to display a list using Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, uikit

The iPhone has the UITableView for displaying lists and information, what is the best way to display the same type of lists using Cocoa for an OSX application? I'm trying to convert one of my iPhone apps to the desktop using Cocoa, but having a hard time finding the same type of list view.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [NSTableView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).